# laravel eloquent relationship multiple

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is my products model

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

and this is my Orders model

```
 public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
 }
 public function product(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
 }
```

and my order table structure

[image]

this is my response as of now (I'm using Order model).

```
{
    id: 11,
    quantity: 2,
    customer: {
        id: 6,
        name: "saging",
        email: "saging@gmail.com",
        role_id: 3,
    },
    items: {
        id: 7,
        name: "Pellentesque semper",
        description: "raesent sit amet elementum purus. ",
        price: "72.21",
        cover_image: "7CPVS7yjqba9iJ7J.jpg",
    }
},

{
    id: 12,
    quantity: 2,
    customer: {
        id: 6,
        name: "saging",
        email: "saging@gmail.com",
        role_id: 3,
    },
    items: {
        id: 3,
        name: "Donec nec mattis ligula",
        description: "Pellentesque semper, augue at aliquet tincidunt",
        price: "33.21",
        cover_image: "ZJbbzjPwDXrcbkwi.jpg",
    }
 }
```

the code that im currently using is

```
$products = Order::with('user','product');
return OrdersResource::collection($products->paginate(5));
```

and im listing the `products and customer` by using the methods in my `Order Model`

the output that i want is like this

```
{
    id: 12,
    quantity: 2,
    customer: {
        id: 6,
        name: "saging",
        email: "saging@gmail.com",
        role_id: 3,
    },
    items: [
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Donec nec mattis ligula",
            description: "Pellentesque semper, augue at aliquet tincidunt",
            price: "33.21",
            cover_image: "ZJbbzjPwDXrcbkwi.jpg",
        },
        {
            id: 7,
            name: "Pellentesque semper",
            description: "raesent sit amet elementum purus. ",
            price: "72.21",
            cover_image: "7CPVS7yjqba9iJ7J.jpg",
        }
    ]
 }
```

this is my OrderResource Code

```
$sub_total = $this->quantity * $this->product->price;
$discount = round((10 / 100) * $sub_total, 2);
$total = $sub_total - $discount;

return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'quantity' => $this->quantity,
    'address' => $this->address,
    'sub_total' => $sub_total,
    'discount' => $discount,
    'total_price' => $total,
    'created_at' => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:i:s A'),
    'customer' => $this->user,
    'items' => $this->product,
    ];
```

Is my relationship wrong? I'm new to laravel and the eloquent relationship is the part where i always skipped because I'm confuse. But now i have to face it.

Comment: I think you missed the id here `id: 11,` it's 12 no ? and please add the OrdersResource code :)

Comment: edited.........

Comment: whats the problem ? you have added belongsTo relation between Order and Product then it will be always a single item

Comment: ohh i tried belongsToMany but im confused with it also because i have no idea what is pivot table i dont know where to start lol

Comment: what i want is to display many item in order

Comment: if you want to display multiple Products for single order then create a separate table `product_order` and place order_id, product_id and quantity in that table. After that create manyToMany relationship between Order and Product model using `product_order` as pivot table

Comment: can u show an example sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `product_id` and `quantity` from `orders` table and create a table `order_product` like this

```
order_product(id, order_id, product_id, quantity)
```

**Order model**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Product model**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')->withPivot('quantity')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Now create a `ProductResource` class

```
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'description' => $this->description,
    'price' => $this->price,
 ];
```

Now change in `OrderResource` class

```
$sub_total= 0;
$quantity = 0;

foreach($this->products as $product){
  $sub_total += ($product->pivot->quantity * $product->price);
  $quantity += $product->pivot->quantity;
}

$discount = round((10 / 100) * $sub_total, 2);

$total = $sub_total - $discount;

return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    'address' => $this->address,
    'sub_total' => $sub_total,
    'discount' => $discount,
    'total_price' => $total,
    'created_at' => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:i:s A'),
    'customer' => $this->user,
    'items' => ProductResource::collection($this->products),
    ];
```

After creating order, insert order product like this

```
$order->products()->attach([
    10 => ['quantity' => 1],
    22 => ['quantity' => 2]
]);
```

**Here 10 and 22 is a product id**

Check details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: sir before im inserting the data only on orders table but now because of order_product table. Im inserting now the  data in that 2 tables is that correct?

Comment: in what table does that insert fall into? is that on order table and order_product?

Comment: that will go to `pivot` table named `order_product`. read my answer from top

Comment: sir im using it like this $table = OrderProduct::with('product'); and im attaching it with $table->product()->attach($orders); and im getting an error query builder products not exist

Comment: why `OrderProduct`, just create an order normally you do without `product_id` and `quantity` and then create `$order->products()->attach`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177561/discussion-between-rkj-and-beginner).

Comment: are u still there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738846/mysql-query-in-a-form-of-laravel-eloquent-orm

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in the relationships between order and products, you have to set a Many to Many relationship, for that you will need :

- Create a third table name it `order_product` is should contain `order_id` and `product_id`
- set the relationsips in the models :

  `Product` model :

  ```
  public function orders()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
  }
  ```

  `Order` model :

  ```
  public function products()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
  }
  ```
- Finally you have to create a `ProductResource` and in the `OrderResource` you have to do it like this :

  ```
  return [
      'id' => $this->id,
      'quantity' => $this->quantity,
      'address' => $this->address,
      'sub_total' => $sub_total,
      'discount' => $discount,
      'total_price' => $total,
      'created_at' => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:i:s A'),
      'customer' => $this->user,
      'items' => ProductResource::collection($this->products)
      ];
  ```

Comment: sir on my order table do i need to remove the column product_id and user_id?

Comment: forgot about that remove only the product_id but the user_id it will be used for the user relationship leave it ;)

Comment: okay sir ill try. But how does the order_product table relate to that two model because i dont see any connection ? thanks sir

Comment: all you have to do is add the columns prder_id and product_id and set the relationship and laravel will do the magic behind the scenes ;)