# mysql query in a form of laravel eloquent many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a query

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) as quantity FROM `order_product` GROUP BY product_id
```

the order_product is the pivot table of products and orders in which they have many to many relationship

This is my model relationship

Order model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Product model

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')->withPivot('quantity')->withTimestamps();
}
```

how can i use this in a form of laravel eloquent?

Comment: `order_product` is a pivot table between `order` and `product` right ?

Comment: yes sir........

Comment: is that the proper way of fetching all of the results in order_product pivot table? because i make a model for this pivot table and just fetch all of the result.

Comment: it is okay now..

Comment: i have added answer check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch it like this

```
$products = Product::with('orders')->get(); //always eager load orders relation
```

Now print it

```
foreach($products as $product){
      echo $product->orders->sum(pivot.quantity);
}
```

Comment: im trying it now sir

Comment: sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742584/laravel-api-resource-add-other-data

Comment: sir check the link

Comment: @Beginner added answer check there