# accessing the accessor from different model with many to many relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Supposed i have an `accessor` to my `Product` model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function getIncomeAttribute() { 
        $sub_total = $this->price * $this->quantity; 
        $discount = round((10 / 100) * $sub_total, 2); 
        return round(($sub_total - $discount), 2); 
    }

    public function orders(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)->withPivot('quantity')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

My product model has a many to many relationship with order, this is my `order model`

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('quantity')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

from my order how can i access the accessor in my product model? i tried this `$this->products->quantity`, but the error is `Property [income] does not exist on this collection instance`

this is my `OrderResource` that extends `JsonResource` where i tried to used the `$this->products->income`

```
public function toArray($request){
    $sub_total= 0;
    foreach($this->products as $product){
        $sub_total += ($product->pivot->quantity * $product->price);
    }
    $discount = round((10 / 100) * $sub_total, 2);
    $total = round(($sub_total - $discount), 2);
    $sub_total = round($sub_total,2);
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'address' => $this->address,
        'sub_total' => $sub_total,
        'discount' => $discount,
        'total_price' => $this->products->quantity,
        'created_at' => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:i:s A'),
        'customer' => $this->user,
        'items' => ProductsResource::collection($this->products)
      ];
 }
```

Comment: where do you want to access it ?

Comment: in my order, or the other solution is to make an accessor on the order model?

Comment: yes, create accessor in order model. you can access that using `$product->income` but in current case that will not give you correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `subTotal` accessor  in Order Model

Order Model

```
public function getSubTotalAttribute() {  //calculate product subtotal 
   $sub_total = 0;

   foreach($this->products as $product){
      $sub_total += ($product->pivot->quantity * $product->price);
   }

   return $sub_total;
}
```

Now use it in `OrderResource`

public function toArray($request){

```
$discount = round((10 / 100) * $this->subTotal, 2); 

$totalPrice = round(($this->subTotal - $discount), 2); 

return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'address' => $this->address,
    'sub_total' => $this->subTotal,
    'discount' => $discount,
    'total_price' => $totalPrice,
    'created_at' => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:i:s A'),
    'customer' => $this->user,
    'items' => ProductsResource::collection($this->products)
  ];
```

}

**Note:** When you fetch `Order` then eager load `Product`

Comment: Sir i have a question, how can i show the pivot table? In my order

Comment: order resource*

Comment: why do you need to show the pivot table, you can access all of its property using `Product` and `Order` model. check documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: what you need to access ?

Comment: lmao when i use the return parent::toArray($request) i see now the pivot table but when i manipulate the return it doesnt show the pivot lol

Comment: use `$this->pivot` in OrderResource it will give you order_product table pivot fields. for example you can use `$this->pivot->quantity`

Comment: sir check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781604/convert-created-at-column-in-laravel-to-y-m-d-format-in-wherebetween-query

Comment: hey man are u there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959140/laravel-request-validation-on-updating-of-data