# convert created_at column in laravel to y-m-d format in whereBetween query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

this is my controller

```
public function index(){
    $products = Order::whereHas('user', function ($query) {
    if(request()->has('d') && request()->get('d')){
        $arr = [
           'start' => Carbon::parse(substr(request()->get('d'), 4, 11))->format('Y-m-d'),
           'end' =>  Carbon::parse(substr(request()->get('d'), 64, -44))->format('Y-m-d')
                ];
            $builder = $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$arr['start'],$arr['end']]);
           }
        });
   return OrdersResource::collection($orders->latest()->paginate(5));
    }
```

my array `$arr` looks like this

```
array:2 [
  "start" => "2018-08-07"
  "end" => "2018-08-09"
]
```

How can i change the created_at `(which is a datetime)` column in laravel to only Year month day format

I need to convert the created_at to that format in order to perform the whereBetween query of laravel because it didn't give me the exact result

Comment: you can use `DB::raw('DATE(created_at)')` in where, both answer will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of change the format of the `created_at` column, I suggest that you should update the `start` and `end` to beginning of the first date and the ending of the last date. The `Carbon` objects should be passed to the `whereBetween` method instead of their string representation.

```
$arr = [
   'start' => Carbon::parse(substr(request()->get('d'), 4, 11))->startOfDay(),
   'end' =>  Carbon::parse(substr(request()->get('d'), 64, -44))->endOfDay()
];

// Both `start` and `end` are Carbon objects
$builder = $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$arr['start'],$arr['end']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used mysql `DATE()` function

```
$builder = $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), [$arr['start'],$arr['end']]);
```

if you want to change the date format, `DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')`

Dont forget to import `DB`

```
use DB;
```