# Appending current url with the new one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a request with this URL

```
expenses?startDate=2019-05-09&endDate=2019-05-15
```

now what I wanted is to append the `startDate=2019-05-09&endDate=2019-05-15` to the new request URL so that I can go to the second page with the current result

```
expenses?pages=2&startDate=2019-05-09&endDate=2019-05-15
```

I tried

```
$builder->latest()->paginate(10)->appends(request()->query());
```

but when i click to my pagination it is not appending thus I get only

```
expenses?pages=2
```

any idea how can I achieve this?

PS. im not using blade

Comment: `$builder->latest()->paginate(10)->appends(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::except('page'))` is this working? OR `$builder->latest()->paginate(10)->appends(request()->except('page'))->links()`

Comment: still not and it is still the same

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19441) for more help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically append query string to laravel pagination links?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52664376/2260604) check solution by Rasmus Christoffer Nielsen

Comment: i just dont understand why it doesnt append the new url. Btw my pagination is built on front end and it just fetches data on the base on the page links. im not using blade templating engine

Answer (score 0):

I think you are little bit confused. `request()->query()` will be available only in page 1 but after it will be **null**.

So you are getting only the `page` in  get method.

In your blade try this:

```
{{
$paginatorVar->appends(request()->input())->links()
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//in your query
$query = Model::paginate(25); // your query with all conditions
$query->appends(request()->query());

return $query;

// in blade add if need
$query->appends(request()->input())->links();
```